# Write string using pyserial to move servo

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, servo

I have an arduino program which allows me to move a servo based on a specific instruction in this format <C,28,355>. Whenever I enter this command in arduino IDE in the serial monitor it seems to work well, but when trying the same command using pyserial in python nothing happens.

```
import serial
arduinoData = serial.Serial('com7', 115200)

while True:
 cmd=“<C,28,355>”
 arduinoData.write(cmd.encode())
```

Comment: Do you need a newline at the end?  Do you have to press "enter" to make it work in the IDE?

Comment: You should update your code with the correct quotation marks.

Comment: Yes  I have to press enter in IDE to make it work.

Comment: What are the correct quotation marks?

Comment: Correct question mark is `"`, not `”`. It is subtle, but it is not the same thing.

Comment: The `encode()` method encodes the string using the specified encoding. If no encoding is specified, UTF-8 will be used. Arduino doesn't use UTF-8, try `encore('ascii')` or just simply send the string.